# i can not acccess to my modem through the pc

Tags: drivers, port

I have a Huawei E5573Bs-320 modem

I'm trying to connect it to a PC, but it does not work.  I found the modem in a CD ROM section, not in the port, So I think I need the right driver to make it work. I searched for the driver and downloaded many Huawei Modems drivers but none worked with me.

Can anyone guide me to find the right driver or a solution for this problem?

Comment: The driver, for Windows, should be in that "CD-ROM", actually a temporary mass storage device for that purpose exactly. If not for Windows you need to provide that information.

Comment: This device is a wireless hotspot. It does not require any driver - only that your computer has a WIFI card.

Answer (score 1):

The E5573Bs is not a modem. It is a (simple) mobile 3G/4G WiFi hotspot (MiFi).

The purpose of the USB port is for charging and/or powering the device and for exposing a small internal storage device (the "CD-ROM" you found). None of the available documentation mentions USB 4G modem functionality.

The internal storage usually has some documentation or apps on it for managing the device.